# Is there a before() function in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, automated-tests, protractor, hierarchy

I am aware there is a beforeEach() function which I am currently using.

However, I would like to be able to run a before function for all my parent level 'describes' and not the 'it' functions within them.

For example my test looks like this (with an x in front of the functions beforeEach executes):

```
    beforeEach: login/out stuffs
x   describe: create first case
x       it: make selections
x       it: add details
x       it: change confidentiality settings
x       it: etc
x   describe: create second case
x       it: make selections
x       it: add details
x       it: change confidentiality settings
x       it: etc
```

Now below is how I want my test to look (with an x in front of the functions I WANT beforeEach to execute):

```
beforeEach: login/out stuffs
x   describe: create first case
        it: make selections
        it: add details
        it: change confidentiality settings
        it: etc
x   describe: create second case
        it: make selections
        it: add details
        it: change confidentiality settings
        it: etc
```

Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: In your first block of code, there are `x`s next to the describe calls. Is that right, that currently `beforeEach` executes before `it` _and_ before `describe`?

Comment: Actually, nothing happens under the describe function apart from holding the it function, so I guess no, just for the it's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to split the two describe blocks in to 2 separate spec files. I figured this made more sense anyway, as each test had different conditions it needed to meet, and it isn't much hassle to have extra spec files.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, it is an intention design choice that tests are run from scratch for each `it`. Otherwise, each it could make state changes that would cause a sibling to fail.

Comment: I read somewhere that Karma used to use a before function that would only operate on the parent level, and they then added another function to cover hierarchy's. So there must be a way we can force protractor to do this even if it may not be strictly 'possible'.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function you are looking for is `beforeAll()`. You can add a before all inside each describe. Make sure that you are using Jasmine 2.

Comment: I was initially using beforeAll() and didn't have any success with it then or now. I think I have found a solution which I guess I'll post if I can make it work.